# How to filter fields from the database in JSON response?

Tags: rest, go, json-api

i am making a REST API in golang and i want to add support for filtering fields but i don't know the best way to implement that, lets say i have this structure representing an `Album` model

```
type Album struct {
  ID            uint64    `json:"id"`
  User          uint64    `json:"user"`
  Name          string    `json:"name"`
  CreatedDate   time.Time `json:"createdDate"`
  Privacy       string    `json:"privacy"`
  Stars         int       `json:"stars"`
  PicturesCount int       `json:"picturesCount"`
}
```

and a function that returns an instance of an `Album`

```
func GetOne(id uint64, user uint64) (Album, error) {

  var album Album

  sql := `SELECT * FROM "album" WHERE "id" = $1 AND "user" = $2;`

  err := models.DB.QueryRow(sql, id, user).Scan(
    &album.ID,
    &album.User,
    &album.Name,
    &album.CreatedDate,
    &album.Privacy,
    &album.Stars,
    &album.PicturesCount,
  )

  return album, err

}
```

and the client was to issue a request like this
`https://api.localhost.com/albums/1/?fields=id,name,privacy`

obvious security issues aside, my first thought was to filter the fields in the database using something like this

```
func GetOne(id uint64, user uint64, fields string) {

  var album Album

  sql := fmt.Sprintf(`SELECT %s FROM "album" WHERE "id" = $1 AND "user" = $2;`, fields)

  // i don't know what to do after this

}
```

and then i thought of adding `omitempty` tag to all the fields and setting the fields to their zero value before encoding it to JSON,

- **would this work?**
- **which one is the better way?**
- **is there a best way?**
- **how would i go about implementing the first method?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first proposal (querying only the requested fields) there are two  approaches (answering "would this work?" and "how would I go about implementing the first method?"):

1. Dynmaically reate a (possibly anonymous) `struct` and generate JSON from there using `encoding/json`.
2. Implement a wrapper that will translate the `*database/sql.Rows` you get back from the query into JSON.

For approach (1.), you will somehow need to create `struct`s for any combination of attributes from your original `struct`. As [`reflect` cannot create a new struct type at runtime](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/T4YkIBkaziE), your only chance would be to [generate them at compile time](https://blog.golang.org/generate). The combinatorial explosion will bloat your binary, so do not do that.

Approach (2.) is to be handled with caution and can only be a last resort. Taking the list of requested fields and writing out JSON with the values you got from DB sounds straightforward and does not involve reflection. However your solution will be (very likely) much more unstable than `encoding/json`.

When reading your question I too thought about using the `json:"omitempty"` struct tag. And I think that it is the preferable solution. It does neither involve metaprogramming nor writing your own JSON encoder, which is a good thing. Just be aware of the implications in case some fields are missing (client side maybe has to account for that). You could query for *all* attributes *always* and override the unwanted ones using reflection.

In the end, all above solutions are suboptimal, and the best solution would be to not implement that feature at all. I hope you have a solid reason to make attributes variable, and I am happy to further clarify my answer based on your explaination. However, if one of the attributes of a resource is too large, it maybe should be a sub-resource.

Comment: i went with `json:omitempty` and set all non requested fields to their zero value using reflection, i don't understand what you mean by "in case somefields are missing"?

Comment: Without `json:"omitempty"` you'd send `{ "name": "", ... }`, but with `json:"omitempty"` your answer would not contain a "name" attribute in case it's value is the empty string. Thus a client (quite likely a browser) that receives the JSON, will not see the empty string but `undefined` for the "name" property. This could cause unexpected behaviour.

Did my answer help? If so, please consider marking it as correct.

Comment: that is not a problem in this specific case because I have no nullable fields in my database.

Comment: I didn't mean to offend and I did not assume your database is all `NOT NULL`, sorry. Just mind that `NULL` in a database, a [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) in Go and [the empty values in`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) (false, 0, any nil pointer or interface value, and any array, slice, map, or string of length zero) are not the same by definition. The number 0 is a valid value for a `NOT NULLABLE` column, but will be omitted in JSON output, for example.

Comment: no worries I wasn't offended, you are right and that is why I made those fields a pointer type.